# Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 4. Actual: 5

Tags: google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YBXUdUJ8P-JT2MJznt8DseayhmHvkzQrGTF4AhVfi4U/edit#gid=0

I'm trying to filter the `Datas` tabs to only display some channels (Sports one).

The issue here, is when the filter doesn't match a row.
For example, if I remove the lines 10 and 11 from `Datas` tab, the second tab works and I can see all the Sport channels.

The error I get from Google Sheet is:

> Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 4. Actual: 5. `

Do you know why ?

Comment: *Alternative* formula if interested: https://i.imgur.com/jSAYOoI.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fix the Regular Expression Used

The error was on the second part of the formula. Apparently, the pattern used in the Like in the `QUERY()` is not an applicable regular expression for the `REGEXMATCH()` function. The pattern can be converted to a proper regular expression by replacing:

```
REGEXMATCH(Datas!A:A; "FR SPORTS | TV")
```

with:

```
REGEXMATCH(Datas!A:A; "(FR SPORTS \| TV)")
```

New formula:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(Datas!A:A; "select A WHERE A LIKE '%FR SPORTS | TV%'"); "tvg-name=(.*)tvg-logo");"""";""))\FILTER(ROW(Datas!A:A); REGEXMATCH(Datas!A:A; "(FR SPORTS \| TV)"))}
```